# Child object doesn't move with parent bone

Tags: game-engine

I'm working on a game (and thus using the Game Engine) and I have a pistol parented to a bone. When I play the game, the pistol moves with the animation, but the actual location does not change with the character. Here's some images of it happening: 
[image] 
You can see the pistol is in the hand, and it follows the animation for rest. 
[image] 
When I run to another location, the pistol moves like it is running, but stays in the same place.

I can probably take a video of it if that's required.

It is not locked in any way.

Comment: My problem was I had the player mesh moving instead of the actual armature moving so I just had to change the motion actuator to the armature instead of the player mesh. I hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the same applies to the game engine, but when animating the bones don't move the body unless they share the same name as the (vertex group) they are meant to move.

this link shows how to make vertex groups
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1EZZIsiIUA

I assume you already have bones, go into edit mode and make sure each one has a name which matches its appropriate vertex group.

sorry if this doesn't help.

Comment: I don't think this answers what the OP is asking.. (I could be wrong though). I think the OP wants the gun (a separate object) to follow the armature/character object in addition to following the parent bone.

Comment: Gandalf3 is correct, although I have tried deleting the pistol's armature and just making the model parented to the bone, and that didn't work either.